# Remaining height of a div to scroll after fixed

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve is something like this:

I have div1 , div2 , and div3...

div 1 is `position: fixed` `right: 0` with `height: 100%` and `width: 250px`

div 2 is `width: 100%` with `max-height: 300px;`

I want to assign all the remaining height of div1 to div3, 
as I don't know the height of screen so I can not figure the height of div1.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

html

```
  <div id='div1'>
    <div id='div2'>
   </div>

   <div id='div3'>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#div1{
  width:250px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}
#div2{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  float:left;
  height:auto;
  overflow:auto;
}
#div3{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Tell me more specific what you want to do?

Comment: provide some fiddle and more specific explanation.

Comment: There are two working answers for you but actually both downvoted for no reason?

Comment: why down voted my question and answers ????

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) like this:

```
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#div3 {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vwnk9aw/1/

Comment: is flex supported in all browsers and mobile too ??

Comment: It supported from all latest versions of each browser. You can check it [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: and i also wanted that if content overflows the div3 should scroll

Comment: thannkyou soo much one last thing should i use moz or webkit with this so that i supports in all the old ver browsers and mobiles too ??

Comment: You can check the [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) who I posted to the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `display: flex` and the [flexible box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #09c;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#div2 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#div3 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

This is a modern approach which makes it easier for designers and developers to position multiple things and to make them have exactly these effects.

For a good tutorial on flexbox you can check out the [css-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)